# Script Won't Set Permissions with Wildcard

Tags: powershell, wildcard, acl

I have a PowerShell script that I wrote to create a subfolder "Admin", if it doesn't already exist, in over 4000 folders in a shared directory. After creating the subfolders I need the permissions of the subfolders to only be for a specific group within the domain. I get no errors, other than the folder already exist errors on the subfolder, but I let the script run for 12 hours and it never completed. I stopped the script to find that all the Admin subfolders were created but the permissions were not set.

If I take out the `*` wildcard in the `$folder` add input a folder name it works perfectly. How can I get it work with the `*` wildcard so I don't have to manually enter over 4000 folder names?

Here is my script:

```
# If the folder for Equipment Images does not exist, make a new one and set the correct permissions.
$Location = "E:\Images\Equipment\*\"
$file = "E:\Images\Equipment\*\Admin"
foreach ($_ in (Get-ChildItem E:\Images\Equipment\*\)) {
    if (($_.PSIsContainer -AND $_.name -eq "Admin")-eq $false) {
        New-Item -Path $location -Name "Admin" -ItemType directory
        $errorActionPreference = "continue"
    }
    $folder = "E:\Images\Equipment\*\Admin"
    $acl = Get-Acl $folder
    if ($acl.AreAccessRulesProtected) {
        $acl.Access | % {$acl.purgeaccessrules($_.IdentityReference)}
    } else {
        $isProtected = $true 
        $preserveInheritance = $false
        $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($isProtected, $preserveInheritance) 
    }
    $account = "recoequip\folder sales group"
    $rights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::FullControl
    $inheritance = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit"
    $propagation = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None
    $allowdeny = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow

    $dirACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($account,$rights,$inheritance,$propagation,$allowdeny)
    $ACL.AddAccessRule($dirACE)

    Set-Acl -aclobject $ACL -Path $folder
    Write-Host $folder Permissions added
}
```

Comment: (What does this have to do with SQL Server?)

Comment: I am running the script on sql server 2008 r2.

Comment: I don't follow. This is a .ps1 file? How are you "running it on SQL Server"? Even if you are running this from a SQL Server Agent job or something, I don't think the problem has anything to do with SQL Server; you will likely have to solve the wildcard problem no matter where you're running the script from.

Comment: The problem does not have anything to do with sql server I was just adding as much information as possible. I will remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use the wildcard with any Acl cmdlets, I don't think that will work.

Set the permission on a single folder in the loop before, or if you have to do it later, just loop through all the folders and set the permissions on all `admin` folders individually, one by one.

Some tips:

Start with a small sub-set of the 400 folders for testing, and Write-Host the currently processed folder so you can see the progress.

Code sample:

```
Get-ChildItem E:\Images\Equipment\ -Directory -Filter "admin" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {

  $acl = Get-Acl $_.FullName
   ... # do your permission stuff

}
```

Comment: Are you saying to take out the * and put the folder names in 1 by 1?

Comment: @SaraBagford - No, I'm saying loop through all directory to find all `admin` folders and set the permission for each one. I added some code to my answer.

Comment: I agree with the recommendation of looping over the results of `Get-ChildItem` and modifying the ACLs for each individual item, but recursing with a filter might yield undesired results if there are folders named "admin" deeper down in the hierarchy. `Get-ChildItem 'E:\Images\Equipment\*\Admin' -Directory | ForEach-Object ...` should suffice.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf - You are the man. Thank you your code worked perfectly.